# how to print tasklist in descending order of memusage values in java

Tags: shell, process, command-prompt, tasklist

I am very new to java and following the is code and I am not getting any output but if I am using just **tasklist** getting the output of the process that are running . But if I am using **( tasklist | sort /R /+58 )** not getting any output only. Thanks in advance only .

```
 package process;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Someprocess {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist | sort /R /+58");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since pipe symbol is unix or bash symbol , so it might not run in windows shell. Trying running it as .bat file that might solve the problem I think so.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , but i tried that also it is not working

Comment: @KaushikHs if it is not working please don't accept the answer. Accepting an answer is not mandatory.

Comment: oh k . Generally pipe is used to send the output of the left to right of the pipe . trying using the output of tasklist an input to sort .